# Adding a "mailto: link in a Telerik Kendo UI MVC grid

Tags: telerik-mvc

I had the following correspondance going on with Telerik and the bottom line is that they can't help me anymore with the question I asked.

Here is the link to the entire thread:

```
http://www.telerik.com/account/support-tickets/view-ticket.aspx?threadid=611754
```

All I want to do is to find out how to do a "mail to: link in a Telerik ASP.Net for MVC grid.

Here is the main context of it if somebody can help me out:

Nor can I find anything on the web that redirects to a "mailto" link.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Website).Width(300).Filterable(false).Sortable(false).ClientTemplate("<a href='#=Website#'>#=Website#</a>");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what is the problem. Did you try to create a link like this? I do not see anything special here.

```
columns.Bound(m=>m.Foo).ClientTemplate("<a href='mailto:#=Website#'>Email Me</a>")
```

Answer (score 0):

columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate("< a href='mailto:#= Website#' >Send Mail< /a>"

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer and check your code, maybe it is not complete